# Hegel's disproof of Newton

Tags: ho.history-overview, differential-calculus

I know it's not a very comprehensive question but I've nowhere else to ask. A friend relayed to me a portion of a book from Hegel where he seemingly disproves Newton's way of finding a differential. I was not able to find the place he references in the Principia Mathematica and would just like it if someone more knowledgeable than me could shine some light on this.

[image: Hegel's assertion]

Comment: This question fits better at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newton's derivation of the product rule for differentiation is given [here](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Newton/Principia/Bk2Lem2/), in Latin and in English translation. For a discussion, and comparison with Leibniz's approach to the product rule, see [this commentary.](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Book%3A_Real_Analysis_(Boman_and_Rogers)/02%3A_Calculus_in_the_17th_and_18th_Centuries/2.01%3A_Newton_and_Leibniz_Get_Started)